# Need adjective to describe certain kind of speech or communication

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been looking everywhere for a word to characterize speech in a business setting e.g. ny management or HR, where it is filled with buzzwords, circular logic, and devoid of real substance. In writing, I've seen this sort of thing described as fluff. Is there an adjective meaning "filled with fluff"? The closest I've come is vacuous or glib (both meaning empty), but the former word seems to carry an added implication of stupidity and the latter suggests that the speaker is at least eloquent. Is there something between the two? Mundane and devoid of meaning?

Comment: Can this be reopened? It was closed due to similar questions being answered, but all of these answers are regarding nouns and I am looking for an adjective

Answer (score 0):

There is a productive type of combination that will give for many nouns (X) an adjective meaning "full of X". It consists in combining the noun with the adjective "ridden" by means of a hyphen. So, "**fluff-ridden**" is one option of adjective for the use you have in mind.

Note: You do not necessarily find these terms in dictionaries; they might occasionally be found there as examples.